# Не загружаются CSS стили

Tags: .htaccess, php, чпу

Хочу реализовать ЧПУ.

Имею вот так:

`http://localhost/site/f2.php?id=6`

хочу вот так:

`http://localhost/site/f2/6`

Пишу вот так:

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^f2/([0-9]+)/? f2.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Страница нужная выходит, но без загрузки стилей css. Почему так? 
Вроде все верно делаю, буду рад любой помощи. Может, ссылка по созданию ЧПУ. Все, что я нашел, как-то сухо написано. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Абсолютные пути к css прописывайте и будет вам счастье

Comment: Спасибо! А так я все верно написал?

Comment: написал вот так. все равно страница как-будто без стилей(((
<link href="http://localhost/site/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пишешь `^` (начинается с), то указывай и `$` (конец строки).

У тебя вот так будет: `^f2/([0-9]+)(/?)$`.

Comment: Права на стили проверил?

Comment: как их проверять и зачем это нужно?

Comment: написал вот так RewriteRule ^f2/([0-9]+)(/?)$ f2.php?firm=$1 [L] и все равно нет стилей

Comment: когда переходишь по этому урлу http://localhost/site/f2.php?id=6 стили есть вообще? и хотелось бы глянуть на .htaccess сам